# Click dynamic div of menubar which is loaded via jquery

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Im using Selenium 2.44 library with IE 9 browser

The menubar is loaded dynamically via js.I tried to locate the element via `findElement` - used `Xpath`. It ends up in throwing `nosuchElement` exception. below is snippet of Dom element

```
<html><body class="page">
    <div id="dynamicMenu" style="display: block;">
    <ul class="sf-menu  sf-js-enabled sf-shadow">

      <li sequence="7">
       <a class="sf-with-ul" href="UserContentStart.aspx?category=17">Type
       <span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span></a>

       <ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
        <li sequence="0">
         <a href="UserContentStart.aspx?category=19">Brochure</a>
        </li>
        <li sequence="1">
         <a href="UserContentStart.aspx?category=22">Direct mail</a>
        </li>
        <li sequence="2">
         <a href="UserContentStart.aspx?category=21">E-mail</a>
        </li>
        <li sequence="3">
         <a href="UserContentStart.aspx?category=10019">Flyer</a>
        </li>
        <li sequence="4">
         <a href="UserContentStart.aspx?category=18">Poster</a>
        </li>
        <li sequence="5">
         <a href="UserContentStart.aspx?category=20">Presentation</a>
        </li>
        <li sequence="6">
         <a href="UserContentStart.aspx?category=10017">Letter</a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>

    </body></html>
```

Do I need to execute the javascript before finding the element.
I dont have access to source code.All I inspect is via `DOM` element source from F12 dev tool.

Thanks !

Comment: Which element are you trying to find?

Comment: Im trying to click a link which is Presentation 5th one in the list.

Answer (score 0):

`//li[@sequence='5']/a` should work for you. And, before that you have to make sure the element is visible.

Comment: No the element is not visible until I hover the main menu Type which is the first li tag under div <li sequence="7">
       <a class="sf-with-ul" href="UserContentStart.aspx?category=17">Type
       <span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span></a>

Comment: So you probably want to click the first `li` then wait for the fifth `li` and perform action on that

Answer (score 0):

Below Code will find the 5th element and will wait untill it gets visible for 20 sec .
Once its visible it will click the element.
In your case 5th element is the link to '**Presentation**' which is in '**a**' tag.

```
WebDriverWait  Test = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement Fifth_Link = Test.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Presentation')]")));
Fifth_Link.click();
```

Let me know if it does not works.